# consumir serviço REST com totalcross

Tags: java, rest, totalcross

Gostaria de saber como faço para consumir um serviço REST usando o totalcross.

Fiz um exemplo seguindo o que está na documentação, estou usando o HttpStream.

```
String url = enderecoWS + servico;
HttpStream hs = new HttpStream(new URI(url));
byte[] buf = new byte[hs.contentLength];
hs.readBytes(buf, 0, hs.contentLength);
String str = new String(buf);
```

Porem na linha `byte[] buf = new byte[hs.contentLength]`, o valor do `contentLength` está -1 e gera

```
Exception: class java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException.
```

Fiz uma alteração no código acima trocando `hs.contentLength` para `hs.readLine().length()`, desta forma consigo pegar o retorno, porem de uma parte da string.

Outra coisa,  caso eu tenha a seguinte situação:

- Classe Grupo
- Classe Subgrupo

Onde a classe Subgrupo tenha um objeto do tipo grupo. Ao usar o `JSONFactory` dessa forma:

```
Subgrupo[] subgrupoArray = JSONFactory.parse(str, Subgrupo[].class);
```

Dá erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not call newInstance() on the Class for java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alessandro,

No github da TotalCross tem um exemplo de como usar a API para chamadas REST. https://github.com/TotalCross/tcrest

Tenta rodar o exemplo e vê se atende o que você precisa =)

Outra coisa importante é você baixar a última versão do SDK no site www.totalcross.com sempre tem atualizações/correções da API

Comment: Bruno, essas dependencias "com.tc.ui" e "com.tc.utils" não estão no repositório central do Maven. Onde posso baixa-las?

Comment: Alessandro, baixa esses projetos no github. Eles são as dependências que faltam https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-utilities https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-components-renewed https://github.com/TotalCross/magical-utils

Comment: Importei todos os projeto, mas está acusando erro no projeto tc-utilities classe "HttpConn" na linha : opt.setSendData(true);

Comment: Bruno, percebi que alguns exemplos que foram passados, tem referencia a classes da api do Java(JDK) quando vou fazer o deploy ocorre erro devido a estes imports. O que preciso fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: Oi Alessandro, fiz duas pequenas modificações nos projetos. Você pode puxar as alterações e testar?

Answer (score 6):

> Gostaria de saber como faço para consumir um serviço REST usando o totalcross.
>
> [...]
>
> Porem na linha "`byte[] buf = new byte[hs.contentLength]`", o valor do contentLength está -1 e gera

Na definição do serviço, não necessariamente o servidor precisa enviar o tamanho do conteúdo. Para tratar essas situações, no TotalCross se usa o `contentLength == -1`

Fizemos um wrapper para tratar da melhor maneira possível isso, inclusive tratando a parte de receber uma resposta compactada (`gzip` ou `deflate`). O wrapper encontra-se nos utilitários do TotalCross (classe [HttpConn](https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tc/utils/utilities/io/HttpConn.java)).

> Outra coisa, caso eu tenha a seguinte situação:
>
> Classe Grupo Classe Subgrupo
>
> Onde a classe Subgrupo tenha um objeto do tipo grupo, ao usar o JSONFactory, dessa forma:
>
> ```
> Subgrupo[] subgrupoArray = JSONFactory.parse(str, Subgrupo[].class);
> ```

Para o `JSONFactory`, você está passando a classe do array. Você deveria passar `Subgrupo[] subgrupoArray = JSONFactory.parse(str, Subgrupo.class);`

Se `Subgrupo` não for um objeto raso, recomendo usar a API do JSONSimple para tal fim. O `JSONFactory.parse` só consegue interpretar corretamente se o objeto parseado não possuir subobjetos. Então, se `Subgrupo` possuir como tributo um objeto do tipo `OutraClasse`, ocorrerá uma falha no parser.

---

## EDIT

No TotalCross, portamos o repositório do [JSON Simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) para dentro do SDK, de tal sorte que temos um compilador leve (SAX-like) de JSON. Para fazer o parse de um JSON com esse framework, é necessário criar um `ContentHandler`. No próprio repositório original do JSON Simple tem [exemplos disso](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/test/java/org/json/simple/Test.java#L141). Também temos exemplo disso [dentro de um repositório de exemplo](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/master/src/main/java/com/totalcross/sample/bigfile/ui/JsonSimpleShower.java#L56).

Comment: Há exemplos do uso da classe HttpConn nesse [repositório de exemplo](https://github.com/TotalCross/tcrest)

Comment: Tentei usar o exemplo que foi passado. https://github.com/TotalCross/tcrest. Mas está dando erro nas dependências.

Comment: @Alessandro, estamos trabalhando para subir esses códigos todos no Central Maven Repository. Subimos a atualização com o <code>HttpStream.Options</code> em pre.totalcross.com

Comment: Jefferson, não ficou muito claro essa questão do JSONSimple. Poderia me passar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: Ok, eu não tinha reputação para por múltiplos links (vou editar acima também para ficar mais claro). [JSONSimple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) é uma biblioteca de compilação de JSON de uma maneira rápida e direta ao assunto. Usamos a compilação [nesse exemplo](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file). Para fazer a copilação, você deve chamar o `parser` e passar para ele um `ContentHandler` criado por você.. Link direto para o parser que usamos: https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tc/sample/bigfile/ui/JsonSimpleShower.java#L56

Comment: Jefferson, outra questão. Ao efetuar o deploy de uma aplicação de teste que utilizava uma biblioteca de terceiros, me foi mostrado uma mensagem de erro que um import do java(java.lang.awt.Color) utilizada em uma classe dessa biblioteca deveria ser trocada por outra(creio que do totalcross). Posso contornar esse problema?

Comment: Infelizmente, não temos suporte a java.awt.Color =/ Você tem algum controle sobre a biblioteca?

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho controle, pq é a biblioteca do spring. Estou tentando fazer um teste com esse exemplo JSONSimple, mas tá um pouco complicado de entender e ajustar isso no meu projeto.